# Is there a way to downgrade Flex to version 2.5.39 on Ubuntu 20 LTS?

Tags: apt, 20.04

I need to use a tool which needs flex but it's not compiling with 2.6, and the maintainer had said it was not compatible with 2.6 and needs 2.5.39.

I tried the usual `apt install flex=2.5.39` but it is not finding the package. Unfortunately this tool hasn't been maintained for the past 4 years so upgrading it is not really an option.

Is there a way to get flex 2.5.39 on 20.4 LTS?

Comment: You could always obtain the [source code](https://github.com/westes/flex/releases/tag/flex-2.5.39) and build it yourself

Comment: Yeah, but I fear its not that straightforward due to dependencies which might also be old.

Comment: Well you won't know if you don't try it - it built first time with no issues on my 18.04 box

Comment: @steeldriver true, but i prefer to try simpler approaches first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only (and main) version available of `flex` in repositories is `2.6.4-6.2`.

```
$ apt policy flex
flex:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6.4-6.2
  Version table:
     2.6.4-6.2 500
        500 https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

So `apt install flex=2.5.39` won't work.

---

`2.5.39` is only available at `trusty-backports`:

```
$ rmadison flex --arch amd64 | grep 5.39
flex | 2.5.39-8~ubuntu14.04.1 | trusty-backports | amd64
```

You can try backporting it your self: https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation

---

You can also check `flex-old` package and see if it works for you:

```
$ apt search flex-old
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
flex-old/focal 2.5.4a-10ubuntu2 amd64
  Old version of the fast lexical analyzer generator
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Just for the benefit of other readers, I then added `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and did `apt update` then `apt install libfl-dev=2.5.39-8~ubuntu14.04.1 flex=2.5.39-8~ubuntu14.04.1` . `flex --version` shows the right version. You might want to add it to your answer to have it more complete.

Comment: @jbx I'm glad that you managed to solve the problem. However what I meant for you to do was adding `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse` and trying to build the Ubuntu's flex source against the focal libraries. so you wouldn't end up pulling a bunch of dependencies from `trusty-backports`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah looked at it first, but it started to get complicated and I couldn't understand what was going on. At some point the investment in terms of time and effort going around in circles trying to understand what is going on is not worth it. I was just looking for a quick way to solve this (the tool i wanted to use gave a segmentation fault anyway which other users reported and was never investigated, so its good i didnt waste more time on this)